# What's the easiest/fastest way to get tokens?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

As topic says:

What's the easiest/fastest way to get tokens? I collected all of them from achievements that I got. And I know that fastest way is just to purchase them, however it's not what I'm planning to do. I also know that sometimes you get 50 tokens as a daily reward when you collect all 3 *Bapples*.

I also watched the videos to get that 1 free token, but now I'm getting a pop-up that says that there are no videos remaining to watch.

Comment: just install modded aps

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, so there have been some updates.

You can do the special missions, located below the Jelly Lab. Those will get you a whole bunch of tokens. You will get 350 tokens if you complete the whole special mission, usually.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way and fastest way is to buy coins there are no hacks that i know of on dispicable minion rush. Although running to get bapples is fast it is quicker to buy the coins in the shop.

Comment: He said that he doesn't want to spend real life money on them.